# Integrating other python apps in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have multiple python apps that are gathering and doing manipulation with data.

At this moment I use pewee as a database, but I am considering integrating them with Django, mostly because of the Django admin (more easy to manually check/modify data for me and non-devs) instead of building an interface myself.

The external apps run independently one of another and do a lot of database operations. They are gathering data from online and offline(excel, csv) sources, and do not run on a server(can be considered desktop apps).

It is possible to start an app from Django admin, by adding a button ?

What is the best way to add them from a project organization point of view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the app name into **installed_apps** in Django settings file. Then you can use all the features of the app in django.